# RadialGradientBrush and PathGradientBrush in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, gradient

I am looking for a solution to use `RadialGradientBrush` and `PathGradientBrush` in **UWP** XAML.

I can use the `LinearGradientBrush` from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media` like below

```
<StackPanel>
  <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
        <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

I found that “Windows Runtime XAML vocabulary doesn't support RadialGradientBrush and PathGradientBrush” from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.gradientbrush).

**Is there any other work around that we can make to get the functionality of `RadialGradientBrush` and `PathGradientBrush` in UWP XAML? similar to `GDI`**

Note: I cannot use `Win2D` or `Direct2D` for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, these two are not yet supported in UWP, so you must use Win2D (it supports `CanvasRadialGradientBrush`) or alike to simulate them manually...

Answer (score 1):

We've added a Win2D Interop helper to directly support most of the [RadialGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/brushes/RadialGradientBrush) in the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit).